# Java(Apex) RegEx not working?

Tags: java, regex, apex

I am having trouble with a regex in salesforce, apex. As I saw that apex is using the same syntax and logic as apex, I aimed this at java developers also.
I debugged the String and it is correct. `street` equals 'str 3 B'.

When using http://www.regexr.com/, the regex works('\d \w$').

The code:

```
Matcher hasString = Pattern.compile('\\d \\w$').matcher(street);
    if(hasString.matches())
```

My problem is, that `hasString.matches()` resolves to `false`. Can anyone tell me if I did something somewhere wrong? I tried to use it without the `$`, with difference casing, etc. and I just can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `find` instead of `matches` for partial input match as `matches` attempts to match complete input text.

```
Matcher hasString = Pattern.compile("\\d \\w$").matcher(street);
if(hasString.find()) {
   // matched
   System.out.println("Start position: " + hasString.start());
}
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Can't believe I wasted one hour on this! Thanks really much

Comment: Could you maybe tell me, if there is something similar to RegionStart() to use in combination with .find? As this returns "0" with the .find() method(obviously).

Comment: You can use `hasString.start()` (see updated answer)

Comment: You are awesome :)! Thank you, and sorry for my laziness on the second question.